# Unable to determine maven version

Tags: maven, jenkins

We are using Maven 3.0.5 and JDK 1.7.0_55.

I have encountered an error

```
ERROR: Processing failed due to a bug in the code. Please report this to jenkinsci-users@googlegroups.com
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to determine Maven version

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: mavenHome 'C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.0.5' doesn't seem to exist on this node (or you don't have sufficient rights to access it
```

Apache is installed in mentioned path.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the directory `C:\Tools\apache-maven-3.0.5` exist?

Comment: Yes. It exist. @ChadNouis

Comment: Probably jenkins user ID used for connecting to the slave  might not have required access to access c:Drive , Just to confirm that  please copy maven folder to your e:\Drive and execute  the command again by pointing New location and see if error exists.

Comment: Thanks @prudviraj . the user didnt had the access to the slave machine. After giving the access, this issue got resolved.